# I am using the data set "mhw.csv" from https://datahub.io/nl/dataset/mercer-and-hall-wheat-yield-data

Tags: r, statistics

I am currently working with the data set "mhw.csv" , located at https://datahub.io/nl/dataset/mercer-and-hall-wheat-yield-dat
Which is a data frame pertaining

The data frame is separated into 4 columns: 
"r" "c" "wheat" "straw"

Column r is a row number and c is a column number corresponding to an individual plot in the field. The field is 20 x 25. With a length of 500.

I want to divide the data into 4 quadrants, a NorthWest (rows 1:5 and Columns 1:12) NorthEast (rows 1:5 and columns 13:25) SouthWest (rows 5:10 and columns 1:12) SouthEast (rows 5:10 and columns 13:25)

Then add a 5th column to the data.frame that would denote where each of the plot is located.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. This is my first question, I hope I gave enough information.

Thank you!

Comment: You should provide a sample of code so that others can see what you are doing try `dput(head(dataframe))` to produce a sample of th e data set.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not going to go download that data, but using sample data:

```
test1 <- data.frame(r = sample(1:10, 10), c = sample(1:25, 10))
```

The simplest no-frills answer is probably:

```
test1$Quadrant[test1$r<=5 & test1$c<=12] <- "Northwest"
test1$Quadrant[test1$r>5 & test1$c<=12] <- "Southwest"
...
```

Et cetera. Do it for your four quadrants and the dataframe should now have the new column you're looking for.

PS: Generally you'll get quicker answers if you provide a sample dataframe like I did above with 'test1'.